# Why is str.split() not working in with fastapi str type?

Tags: python, string, fastapi

For some reason, str.split() isn't acting as expected inside the fastapi package for python.

To simplify, I've included a simple use-case of FastAPI, but the str.split() seems to only remove the character that I intend to split by, rather than return a list where I can access individual items by their index.  A highly simplified reproducible code:

```
### fastapi example
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

@app.get("/alignment/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: str, q: str):
    my_list = q.split("+")   ### the critical line in question
    return {"people" : my_list[0]}
```

I run this code using uvicorn as:

```
>>> uvicorn main:app --reload
```

By browsing in firefox to 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/alignment/abc123ABC123?q=abracadabra+django+musical

My output is:

```
{"people":"abracadabra django musical"}
```

But, I expect the output to be:

```
{"people" : "abracadabra"}
```

To make sure I wasn't crazy, I took str.split() outside of fastApi, to show the expected result is a list, where I can access each of the accessed items individually by their index, shown here:

```
### str.split example
q = "abracadabra+django+musical"
my_list = q.split("+")
a = my_list[0]
print(a)

>>> abracadabra # Actual result as expected
```

I've had a few hypotheses, but neither have yielded results:

1. the str type declared in fastapi class for read_item doesn't have the same .split() function, is there a way to default to python's base str.split() function?
2. maybe this is an encoding issue, but URL's and python are both ASCII by default, so that doesn't seem to be the error
3. maybe the '+' requires an escape character (as it does in most REGEX situations), but in `### str.split example`(above) it works without any \ or \, so I don't presume it's necessary.

Any help delimiting this string into pieces would be very helpful.  Afterwards, I intend to process the list of strings, and return a much more complex json than just the first element, but this seems to be main the hurdle in my way.

Comment: Could you print `len(my_list)`?

Comment: maybe you should first check the content of string q before splitting. you will get your answer. hint: + sign in url has different meaning. :)

Comment: Do, `print(q)` and `print(my_list)`, and show us their contents, so we give you a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your code will work if you replace `split("+")` with `split(" ")`. `+` characters in a query string represent a [space](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) when url encoded; FastAPI will url decode the query string before passing to the view function.